# Не создавать тег в xml, если содержимое тега равно нулю

Tags: xml, golang

В golang создаю xml с помощью пакета "encoding/xml". Есть некоторые поля в xml, которые при нулевых значениях не надо указывать. Как это можно сделать?

вот пример xml:

```
         <detail>
            <sgtin>12321432432FGHHSDJDJ23423</sgtin>
            <cost>17</cost>
            <vat_value>0.0</vat_value>
            <sale_docs>
                <doc>
                    <doc_type>1</doc_type>
                    <doc_name>cheque</doc_name>
                    <doc_number>3</doc_number>
                    <doc_date>04.04.2017</doc_date>
                </doc>
            </sale_docs>
        </detail>
```

строчку `<vat_value>0.0</vat_value>` надо удалить

ссылка на пример: https://play.golang.org/p/_cc4h-FyA3V

Comment: VatValue обязательно должен быть строкой?

Comment: Нет, вообще, он должен быть float. Там и некоторые другие поля не должны быть строкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type Detail struct {
XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"detail"`
Sgtin    string   `xml:"sgtin"`
Cost     string   `xml:"cost"`
VatValue string   `xml:"vat_value,omitempty"`
SaleDocs *SaleDocs
```

}

Нужно было добавить `omitempty`. Невнимательно читал документацию